# Python for loop, iterate through a string: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I've been having trouble with this for loop that is supposed to iterate through and save a list with all the words in the book.

The error I get is: `'int' object is not iterable`.

```
def create_word_dict ()
    word_list = open("mobydick.txt", "r")
    all_list = word_list.read()
    all_list = all_list.split()
    word_list.close()
    for index in len(all_list):
        all_list[index] = parseString(all_list[index])
    return all_list

# Removes punctuation marks from a string
def parseString (st):
    s = ""

    for ch in st:
        if ch.isalpha() or ch.isspace():
            s += ch
        else:
            s += ""
    return s #return was outside code block
```

Comment: its saying 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: I edited your post to fix all the indentation. What part are you having issues with exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want

```
for index in range(len(all_list)):
   all_list[index]=parseString(all_list[index])
```

since `for i in 5:` means nothing in python(since an int cannot be iterated), however for `i in range(5)` is indeed a valid statement, since a range can be iterated...

however its probably better to just iterate over the objects directly

```
new_list = []
for word in all_list:
    new_list.append(parseString(word))
```

or even better just do a list comprehension

```
new_list = [parseString(word) for word in all_list]
```

Comment: well I doubt its __all__ of the examples ;P but most of the common ones at least

Answer (score 0):

You can speed things up a lot by using some of Python's built-in methods:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as lower, ascii_uppercase as upper
from string import digits, punctuation

# create a translation table which
#   makes the string lowercase and
#   replaces all digits and punctuation with spaces
TRANS = str.maketrans(
    lower + upper +           digits + punctuation,
    lower + lower + " " * len(digits + punctuation)
)

def get_word_list(filename):
    with open(filename) as inf:
        return inf.read().translate(TRANS).split()

words = get_word_list("mobydick.txt")
```

For sake of comparison, on my machine this loads the words from the Gutenberg version of Moby Dick (220231 words) in 0.11 seconds.